# GeoServer REST API replace layer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I'm following the steps shown on [this page](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/extensions/importer/rest_examples.html#replacing-postgis-table-using-the-contents-of-a-csv-file) to replace the contents of a layer with new data but I'm having some issues. I can get it to work but only to update existing properties and add new rows - adding new properties or removing properties doesn't seem to work. The example shown adds a new column.

My steps are:

1. Creating an empty import
2. Add the new data to the import
3. Set the `updateMode` to `REPLACE` by sending this to the task with PUT:

```
        data = {
            "task": {
                "updateMode": "REPLACE",
                "layer" : {
                    "name": old_layer_name,
                    "title": old_layer_name,
                    "nativeName": old_layer_name
                }
            }
        }
```

After steps 1 to 3 my import looks like this:

import:

```
{
  "import": {
    "id": 114,
    "href": "https://xxx/geoserver/rest/imports/114",
    "state": "PENDING",
    "archive": false,
    "targetWorkspace": {
      "workspace": {
        "name": "geonode",
        "isolated": false
      }
    },
    "targetStore": {
      "dataStore": {
        "name": "geonode_data",
        "type": "PostGIS"
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "file",
      "format": null,
      "file": ""
    },
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "href": "https://xxx/geoserver/rest/imports/114/tasks/0",
        "state": "READY"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Task:

```
{
  "task": {
    "id": 0,
    "href": "https://xxx/geoserver/rest/imports/114/tasks/0",
    "state": "READY",
    "updateMode": "REPLACE",
    "data": {
      "type": "file",
      "format": "GeoJSON",
      "file": "testing_occupations_different.geojson"
    },
    "target": {
      "href": "https://xxx/geoserver/rest/imports/114/tasks/0/target",
      "dataStore": {
        "name": "geonode_data",
        "type": "PostGIS"
      }
    },
    "progress": "https://xxx/geoserver/rest/imports/114/tasks/0/progress",
    "layer": {
      "name": "testing_occupations47",
      "href": "https://xxx/geoserver/rest/imports/114/tasks/0/layer"
    },
    "transformChain": {
      "type": "vector",
      "transforms": []
    }
  }
}
```

Layer:

```
{
  "layer": {
    "name": "testing_occupations47",
    "href": "https://xxx/geoserver/rest/imports/114/tasks/0/layer",
    "title": "testing_occupations47",
    "originalName": "testing_occupations_different",
    "nativeName": "testing_occupations47",
    "srs": "EPSG:4326",
    "bbox": {
      "minx": 0,
      "miny": 0,
      "maxx": -1,
      "maxy": -1
    },
    "attributes": [
      {
        "name": "geometry",
        "binding": "org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point"
      },
      {
        "name": "Easting",
        "binding": "java.lang.Double"
      },
      {
        "name": "Northing",
        "binding": "java.lang.Double"
      },
      {
        "name": "Name",
        "binding": "java.lang.String"
      },
      {
        "name": "Occupation",
        "binding": "java.lang.String"
      },
      {
        "name": "Interest",
        "binding": "java.lang.String"
      }
    ],
    "style": {
      "name": "geonode_testing_occupations_different",
      "href": "https://xxx/geoserver/rest/imports/114/tasks/0/layer/style"
    }
  }
}
```

I have noticed some inconsistencies with the example I linked to. The example states that "Check layer to ensure `name` indicates layer to replace, and `nativeName` indicates the table contents to replace:"

```
{
  "layer": {
    "name": "values",
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/imports/1/tasks/0/layer",
    "title": "values",
    "originalName": "replace",
    "nativeName": "replace",
```

And you can see that `name` is the original table, and `nativeName` is the new data (`replace`). But in my case, the `nativeName` and the `name` are both the old layer name. Granted I am sending that in the PUT request but if I leave it out, or set it to the new name, I get the error `"errorMessage": "Schema 'testing_occupations_different' does not exist.",`

Another inconsistency with the example is that the task layer: name is `replace` (the new data) but the layer layer: name is `values` (the old data), but I have not been able to achieve this - setting the layer name on either the task or the layer changes the layer name in both places. I cannot get them to be different.

What I seem to be achieving is populating the existing schema with new data but I want to do is replace the schema and the data, as in the example.

Comment: To replace a data store you need to delete the existing one before adding the new one.

Comment: In the geoserver docs example I linked to the datastore was not deleted first, though.

Comment: I missed where in your question you mentioned that you were using the importer extension